# WiX Installer: Using xslt with heat.exe how do I change the value of the parent Id after finding a parent/child match?

Tags: xslt, wix, heat

I have the following source:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLDIR">
    <Component Id="acuthin.exe" Guid="{0DAD4D00-A40E-420D-B90A-B23B89B72881}">
```

and I want to change INSTALLDIR to TARGETDIR:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
    <Component Id="acuthin.exe" Guid="{0DAD4D00-A40E-420D-B90A-B23B89B72881}">
```

but only if Component Id="acuthin.exe".  I tried the following:

```
<xsl:template match="wix:DirectoryRef[@Id='INSTALLDIR']/wix:Component[@Id='acuthin.exe']">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:attribute name="Id">TARGETDIR</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

but it changed the Id of Component instead of DirectoryRef:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLDIR">
    <Component Id="TARGETDIR">
```

Is there a way to tell it to modify the DirectoryRef Id instead?

Here is my heat command line:

heat" dir "Files\Groupacuthin.exeAutoUpdate" -dr INSTALLDIR -var var.HARVESTDIR -gg -sw -nologo -scom -sreg -sfrag -srd -suid -cg "Groupacuthin.exeAutoUpdate" -t test.xslt -out "Components\Groupacuthin.exeAutoUpdate.wxs"

Here is the source before doing the template match:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLDIR">
            <Component Id="acuthin.exe" Guid="{F48C7EB0-6192-4F92-8FCB-8DC8517572B5}">
                <File Id="acuthin.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.HARVESTDIR)\acuthin.exe" />
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="Groupacuthin.exeAutoUpdate">
            <ComponentRef Id="acuthin.exe" />
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Thanks!

Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to modify is the Id attribute of DirectoryRef, but your template is actually selecting a Component that is a child of DirectoryRef.

Change your template to:

```
<xsl:template match="wix:DirectoryRef[@Id='INSTALLDIR' and wix:Component/@Id='acuthin.exe']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="Id">TARGETDIR</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPJ8LVx

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="DirectoryRef">
        <DirectoryRef>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except @Id"/>
            <xsl:if test="(@Id='INSTALLDIR') and /Wix/Fragment/ComponentGroup/ComponentRef[@Id='acuthin.exe']">
                <xsl:attribute name="Id" select="'TARGETDIR'"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your @match="wix:DirectoryRef[@Id='INSTALLDIR']/wix:Component[@Id='acuthin.exe']" 
instead of use 
@match="wix:DirectoryRef[@Id='INSTALLDIR' and wix:Component/@Id='acuthin.exe']"